# Django/Postgres: Aggregate on RangeField

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, aggregate-functions, django-orm

Is it possible to perform aggregation functions on `Django`'s `RangeField`?

Let's say we have 3 objects with `BigIntegerField` `price_range`.

1st obj: `price_range = [10,5000]`

2nd obj: `price_range = [1,5000]`

3rd obj: `price_range = [100,9000]`

The result of `Max` and `Min` aggregation of these three objects would be:

`min = 1` and `max = 9000`

I'm trying to aggregate `Max` and `Min` this way:

```
MyModel.objects.aggregate(Min('price_range'),Max('price_range'),)
```

Which raises error:

> ProgrammingError: function min(int8range) does not exist LINE 1:
>   SELECT MIN("app_mymodel"."price_range") AS "price_range__min" FROM "app...

Comment: What if the two are not overlapping? Like `[1, 5]` and `[8, 10]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It doesn't matter. I want to get the lowest lower bound and the highest higher bound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain the range bounds with `Upper(..)` and `Lower(..)` so:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Upper, Lower

MyModel.objects.aggregate(
    Min(Lower('price_range')),
    Max(Upper('price_range'))
)
```

But note that in case the ranges do not overlap (like for example `[0, 20]` and `[50, 100]`), you will still get a range `[0, 100]`.

Apparently modern versions of Django require naming the fields as [@EricTheise says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240642/django-postgres-aggregate-on-rangefield/51240745#comment111356462_51240745):

```
from django.db.models.functions import Upper, Lower

MyModel.objects.aggregate(
    low=Min(Lower('price_range')),
    high=Max(Upper('price_range'))
)
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. It's for filtering purposes. Thanks

Comment: Gratefully encountering this answer a couple of years later, Django (3.0.6) gives me a `TypeError: Complex expressions require an alias`. Guided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32407777/1332624) I needed to do the equivalent of `MyModel.objects.aggregate(lower=Min(Lower('price_range')), upper=Max(Upper('price_range')))`