# Query (get) upper bound of RangeField in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, psycopg2

I want to get the upper bound of a RangeField via django queryset.

When you have access to the python object, `my_model.size_range.upper` works. Not inside the query engine, not working with `F`, `When`, `Case`...

```py
class MyModel(models.Model):
    size_range = IntergerRangeField()

MyModel.objects.all().annotate(new_upper=F('size_range__upper') + 1)
```

```
FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'upper' for IntegerRangeField or join on the field not permitted.
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I know it has been a while, but I was looking for a solution to the same sort of problem and found a relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51240745/9712989

Answer (score 4):

I found a semi-solution :

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Upper

MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
      upper=Upper('size_range')
  ).annotate(
      new_upper=F('upper') + 1
  )
```

Which feels clumsy but at least it werks

If anyone knows better ? I am sure it is possible to query directly the raw value.

Comment: This is an interesting hack since the SQL function Upper is both used to uppercase a string and get the upper bound of a range.

Works with both `Lower` and `Upper`.

I was looking for a way to filter instances with range higher than a certain value.


`MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
     size_range_lower=Lower('size_range')
).filter(
    size_range_lower__gt=5
)`

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with it? You might be able to use [`endswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#endswith)

```
MyModel.objects.filter(size_range__endswith=some_value))
```

Comment: I need to calculate another field from this one (and others), so I cant simply use it to filter.

Answer (score 0):

With django you can register [custom lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-lookups/).

```
IntegerRangeField.register_lookup(MyCustomLookup)
```

However you cannot register `Upper` directly on the `RangeField` or `IntegerRangeField` because by default the loopup uses the same field as `output_field` (Ex: the type you want is not an `IntegerRangeField` but an `IntegerField`). The `output_field` has to be explicited.

The custom lookup for `IntegerRangeField` with `Upper` would look like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import IntegerRangeField
from django.db.models.functions import Upper


class IntegerRangeUpper(Upper):
    output_field = IntegerRangeField.base_field()


IntegerRangeField.register_lookup(IntegerRangeUpper)


MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
   new_upper=F('size_range__upper') + 1
)
```

Since it could be useful to have this on all type of range fields and it would be very repetitive to register all permutation by hand for the range fields with the lookups, the process can be generalized.

This code creates new lookup classes based on the originals using the  `base_field` as `output_field` and register them on the field.

```
import itertools

from django.contrib.postgres.fields import IntegerRangeField, BigIntegerRangeField, DateRangeField, DateTimeRangeField, DecimalRangeField
from django.db.models.functions import Lower, Upper


def register_range_lookup(
    field, lookup_class
):
    class CustomLookup(lookup_class):
        output_field = field.base_field()

    field.register_class_lookup(CustomLookup)    


for range_field, lookup_class in itertools.product(
    [
        IntegerRangeField,
        BigIntegerRangeField,
        DateRangeField,
        DateTimeRangeField,
        DecimalRangeField,
    ],
    [Lower, Upper],
):
    register_range_lookup(range_field, lookup_class)
```

Also, `__lower` and `__upper` can now be used like this for filtering:

```
# Gets all instances where the lower bounds are greater than 5
MyModel.objects.all().filter(
    size_range__lower__gt=5
)
```