# Return Upper Date in DateTimeTZRange

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a  model where i have a field called date range. which returns a range of date range both the date range is same but the time changes how can i access one date from range in the model using ORM.

```
class My_model(models.Model):
     date_range = ranges.DateTimeTZRange()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can be accessed with `upper` and `lower`

```py
obj = My_model.objects.all().first()
obj.date_range.upper
obj.date_range.lower
```

That field also inherents from `RangeField`
It's all in [contrib\postgres\fields\ranges.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/_modules/django/contrib/postgres/fields/ranges/#DateTimeRangeField) if that helps at all

And here's some Query Stuff I you need: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-range-fields

---

#### Edit, Aggregate

Source: [Django/Postgres: Aggregate on RangeField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51240642/django-postgres-aggregate-on-rangefield)

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Upper, Lower
aggrDict = My_model.objects.all().aggregate(
    low=Min(Lower('date_range')),
    high=Max(Upper('date_range'))
)
print(aggrDict['low'])
print(aggrDict['high'])
```

---

#### Edit 2, filter

If you just want to return items that are 20 days away you could do:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
twenty_days_in_the_future = (datetime.now()+timedelta(days=20)).date()

from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField
My_model.objects.filter(date_range__startswith=twenty_days_in_the_future)


# It might need a __date, idk
My_model.objects.filter(date_range__startswith__date=twenty_days_in_the_future)
```

All Range filters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-range-fields

Comment: it works exactly how you queried but with filter queryset it throws object has no attribute date_range

Comment: does it say **Queryset** object has no attribute?- then we want an `aggregate` function

Comment: Added Aggregate (I missed the `.all()` ) on first upload, that's why I'm making this comment

Comment: First of all Thanks for your answers i actually need to check if todays date is 20 days before date_range and i have some other fields in my filtering query which i check for

Comment: I added the filter, you could also tac on the `__gte` or `__lte` (greater than / equal and less than / equal) ..hopefully I'm not misunderstanding the **check** ..there is a way, with conditional statements, to have an annotated Boolean for if it's 20 days away.. I can provide that, idk how much use you'd get from it tho

Comment: Unsupported lookup 'lower' for DateTimeRangeField or join on the field not permitted. I used both your queries.

Comment: try `My_model.objects.filter(date_range__startswith=twenty_days_in_the_future)` ..I probably should have looked at my own link i put in there- in the original post there's a link for all the range queries

Comment: The query is returning empty query set although i have changed days to 84 to match 'start_end_range': DateTimeTZRange(datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 20, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 30, 20, 30)